# How to loop through each row of dataFrame in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, for-loop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

E.g

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sample=sqlContext.sql("select Name ,age ,city from user")
sample.show()
```

The above statement prints theentire table on terminal. But I want to access each row in that table using `for` or `while` to perform further calculations.

Comment: I believe I provided a correct answer. Can you select, or provide feedback to improve?

Answer (score 79):

You simply cannot. `DataFrames`, same as other distributed data structures, are not [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) and can be accessed using only dedicated higher order function and / or SQL methods.

You can of course `collect`

```
for row in df.rdd.collect():
    do_something(row)
```

or convert  `toLocalIterator`

```
for row in df.rdd.toLocalIterator():
    do_something(row)
```

and iterate locally as shown above, but it beats all purpose of using Spark.

Comment: Newbie question: As iterating an already collected dataframe "beats the purpose", from a dataframe, how should I pick the rows I need for further processing?

Comment: Did some reading and looks like forming a new dataframe with `where()` would be the Spark-way of doing it properly.

Comment: "it beats all purpose of using Spark" is pretty strong and subjective language. The `collect()` method exists for a reason, and there are many valid uses cases for it. Once Spark is done processing the data, iterating through the final results might be the only way to integrate with/write to external APIs or legacy systems.

Answer (score 70):

To "loop" and take advantage of Spark's parallel computation framework, you could define a custom function and use map.

```
def customFunction(row):

   return (row.name, row.age, row.city)

sample2 = sample.rdd.map(customFunction)
```

or

```
sample2 = sample.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.name, x.age, x.city))
```

The custom function would then be applied to every row of the dataframe. Note that sample2 will be a `RDD`, not a dataframe.

Map may be needed if you are going to perform more complex computations. If you just need to add a simple derived column, you can use the `withColumn`, with returns a dataframe.

```
sample3 = sample.withColumn('age2', sample.age + 2)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to actually use the customFunction so that the return values could be used inside a loop for further procesing? I have a collect() based approach but my data is too large and it causes the Pyspark (v. 3) to fail. Thank you!

Comment: hi @David, if I use map() on a rdd, will each row run customFunction() in order? In my case, I hope every row will be processed sequentially.

Answer (score 14):

Using list comprehensions in python, you can collect an entire column of values into a list using just two lines:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("show tables in default")
tableList = [x["tableName"] for x in df.rdd.collect()]
```

In the above example, we return a list of tables in database 'default', but the same can be adapted by replacing the query used in sql().

Or more abbreviated:

```
tableList = [x["tableName"] for x in sqlContext.sql("show tables in default").rdd.collect()]
```

And for your example of three columns, we can create a list of dictionaries, and then iterate through them in a for loop.

```
sql_text = "select name, age, city from user"
tupleList = [{name:x["name"], age:x["age"], city:x["city"]} 
             for x in sqlContext.sql(sql_text).rdd.collect()]
for row in tupleList:
    print("{} is a {} year old from {}".format(
        row["name"],
        row["age"],
        row["city"]))
```

Answer (score 9):

[Give A Try Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RRqG.png)

```
    result = spark.createDataFrame([('SpeciesId','int'), ('SpeciesName','string')],["col_name", "data_type"]); 
    for f in result.collect(): 
        print (f.col_name)
```

Answer (score 8):

It might not be the best practice, but you can simply target a specific column using `collect()`, export it as a list of Rows, and loop through the list.

Assume this is your df:

```
+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+ 
|      Date|  New_Date|      New_Timestamp|date_sub_10|date_add_10|time_diff_from_now|
+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+ 
|2020-09-23|2020-09-23|2020-09-23 00:00:00| 2020-09-13| 2020-10-03| 51148            | 
|2020-09-24|2020-09-24|2020-09-24 00:00:00| 2020-09-14| 2020-10-04| -35252           |
|2020-01-25|2020-01-25|2020-01-25 00:00:00| 2020-01-15| 2020-02-04| 20963548         |
|2020-01-11|2020-01-11|2020-01-11 00:00:00| 2020-01-01| 2020-01-21| 22173148         |
+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
```

to loop through rows in Date column:

```
rows = df3.select('Date').collect()

final_list = []
for i in rows:
    final_list.append(i[0])

print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something to each row in a DataFrame object, use `map`. This will allow you to perform further calculations on each row. It's the equivalent of looping across the entire dataset from `0` to `len(dataset)-1`.

Note that this will return a PipelinedRDD, not a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

above

```
tupleList = [{name:x["name"], age:x["age"], city:x["city"]}
```

should be

```
tupleList = [{'name':x["name"], 'age':x["age"], 'city':x["city"]}
```

for `name`, `age`, and `city` are not variables but simply keys of the dictionary.

Comment: Is a square bracket missing from right hand side of code line 2?

Comment: When you're not addressing the original question, don't post it as an answer but rather prefer commenting or suggest edit to the partially correct answer.