# Pairwise Operations between Rows of Spark Dataframe (Pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cosine-similarity

I have a `Spark Dataframe` with two columns: `id` and `hash_vector`. 
The `id` is the id for a document and `hash_vector` is a `SparseVector` of word counts corresponding to the document (and has size 30000). There are ~100000 rows (one for each document) in the `Dataframe`.

Now, I want to find similarities between every pair of documents. For this I want to compute cosine similarities from the column `hash_vector`. I may also want to try other similarity measures like the Jaccard index. What would be a good way of doing this? I am using PySpark. I have a few ideas:

1. I can use `columnSimilarities` to find the pairwise dot products. But [I read](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6611/item-item-similarity-based-on-text) that it is more efficient for a corpus with size_of_vocabulary >> number_of_documents (which is not the case here)
2. I can loop through the `Dataframe` rows, and for the i-th row, add the i-th row as a column `new_column` to the `Dataframe`, then write a `udf` which finds the similarity (cosine or Jaccard) on the two columns: `hash_vector` and `new_column`. But [I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349281/how-to-loop-through-each-row-of-dataframe-in-pyspark) that looping through rows beats all purpose of using Spark.
3. Lastly, I store only similarities above a certain threshold. Since I have a lot of documents, I can expect the matrix of similarities to be quite sparse.

I know this is a broad question. But I am interested in knowing how an expert would think of going about this. I appreciate any direction.

Comment: Maybe this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46764347/11713502

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a crossjoin of the table with itself? For instance

```
# table alias can be used to disambiguate identically named columns
df_a = df_original.alias('a')
df_b = df_original.alias('b')

# list all possible combinations
# then ignore where it's the same line on both sides
# ordered, so we don't process both (A,B) and then (B,A)
df_cross = df_a.crossJoin(df_b).filter('a.id < b.id')

# now apply a udf
df_similar = df_cross.withColumn('similarity', similarity_udf(col('a.hash_vector'), col('b.hash_vector')))
```