# Find similar strings present in a DataFrame column without using for loop in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a DataFrame containing a column with strings. I want to find similar strings and mark them with some flag. I am using the function [ratio](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/courses/LT1/2011/slides/Python-Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-ratio) from python-Levenshtein module and want to mark strings having a ratio more than 0.90 as "similar". The following is an example of the DataFrame I have:

```
sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
    (1, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
    (2, "Logistic,regression,models,are,neat"),
    (3, "Logistic,regression,model,are,neat")
], ["id", "sentence"])
```

The desired output is:

```
+---+-----------------------------------+------------+
|id |sentence                           |similar_flag|
+---+-----------------------------------+------------+
|0  |Hi I heard about Spark             |            |
|1  |I wish Java could use case classes |            |
|2  |Logistic regression models are neat|2_0         |
|3  |Logistic regression model is neat  |2_1         |
|4  |Logistics regression model are neat|2_2         |
+---+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

Where "2_1" means "2" is the "id" of the reference string (first unique string used for matching) and "1" represents the first string that matches with it. I want to avoid for-loops completely. For smaller data, I have used for-loop to achieve the desired result in simple python and want to have same results in PySpark as well, hence I do not want to use any module other than python-Levenshtein. I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758768/calculating-the-cosine-similarity-between-all-the-rows-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspark) approach, but it requires me to give up python-Levenshtein module. Also my DataFrame is likely to be huge (and expected to grow everyday), so this approach might cause memory errors. Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 3):

I would answer in three steps. Firstly, you need to allow the `df` to look at all options, therefore you might need a Carthesian product of your data using `crossJoin`, such as:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df_new = (
    sentenceDataFrame.crossJoin(
                         sentenceDataFrame.select(
                             f.col('sentence').alias('second_sentence'),
                             f.col('id').alias('second_id')))
)
```

Secondly, have a look at `pyspark.sql.functions.levehstein`. Once your sentences are arranged one against the other, add a new column with Levehstein distance using

```
df_new_with_dist = df_new.withColumn('levehstein_distance',
    f.levenshtein(f.col("sentence"), f.col("second_sentence"))
)

df_new_with_dist.show()

+---+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+
| id|            sentence|     second_sentence|second_id|levehstein_distance|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+
|  0|Hi I heard about ...|Hi I heard about ...|        0|                  0|
|  0|Hi I heard about ...|I wish Java could...|        1|                 27|
|  0|Hi I heard about ...|Logistic,regressi...|        2|                 29|
|  0|Hi I heard about ...|Logistic,regressi...|        3|                 28|
|  1|I wish Java could...|Hi I heard about ...|        0|                 27|
|  1|I wish Java could...|I wish Java could...|        1|                  0|
|  1|I wish Java could...|Logistic,regressi...|        2|                 32|
|  1|I wish Java could...|Logistic,regressi...|        3|                 31|
|  2|Logistic,regressi...|Hi I heard about ...|        0|                 29|
|  2|Logistic,regressi...|I wish Java could...|        1|                 32|
|  2|Logistic,regressi...|Logistic,regressi...|        2|                  0|
|  2|Logistic,regressi...|Logistic,regressi...|        3|                  1|
|  3|Logistic,regressi...|Hi I heard about ...|        0|                 28|
|  3|Logistic,regressi...|I wish Java could...|        1|                 31|
|  3|Logistic,regressi...|Logistic,regressi...|        2|                  1|
|  3|Logistic,regressi...|Logistic,regressi...|        3|                  0|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+
```

Finally, filter out all rows where `id == second_id`. If you wish to stick to your notation of, for example, `2_1`, I recommend you add `groupBy(f.col("id"))` and aggregate on `levehstein_distance` with `f.min()`. Then you can concatenate your IDs, for example with

```
min_dist_df = (
    df_new_with_dist.where(f.col('id') != f.col('second_id'))
                    .groupBy(f.col('id').alias('second_id'))
                    .agg(f.min(f.col('levehstein_distance')).alias('levehstein_distance'))
)


(
    df_new_with_dist.join(min_dist_df,
                          on=['second_id', 'levehstein_distance'],
                          how='inner')
                    .withColumn('similar_flag', f.concat(f.concat(f.col('id'), f.lit('_'), f.col('second_id'))))
                    .select('id', 'sentence', 'similar_flag')
).show()

+---+--------------------+------------+
| id|            sentence|similar_flag|
+---+--------------------+------------+
|  2|Logistic,regressi...|         2_3|
|  1|I wish Java could...|         1_0|
|  0|Hi I heard about ...|         0_1|
|  3|Logistic,regressi...|         3_2|
+---+--------------------+------------+
```

While this is not *exactly* what you asked for, you can filter and tweak on `levehstein_distance` values to get your desired answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is a close enough solution and crossJoin solves the main problem of avoiding for loops. I looked through Spark Python API Docs but couldn't find a function equivalent to Levenshtein Ratio. Levenshtein Distance is also a similar measure but might cause regressions (I have previous results processed using simple python which I need to match). I'll definitely try this solution.