# Iterate Spark data-frame with Hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a very large csv file, so i used spark and load it into a spark dataframe.
I need to extract the latitude and longitude from each row on the csv in order to create a folium map.
with pandas i can solve my problem with a loop:

```
for index, row in locations.iterrows():    

    folium.CircleMarker(location=(row["Pickup_latitude"],
                              row["Pickup_longitude"]),
                    radius=20,
                    color="#0A8A9F",fill=True).add_to(marker_cluster)
```

I found that unlike pandas data-frame the spark data-frame can't be processed by a loop =>[how to loop through each row of dataFrame in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349281/how-to-loop-through-each-row-of-dataframe-in-pyspark) .

so i thought that to i can engenieer the problem and cut the big data into hive tables then iterate them .

is it possible to cut the huge SPARK data-frame in hive tables and then iterate the rows with a loop?

Comment: Please use [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples) guidelines to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't need to iterate over DataFrame or RDD. You only create `transformations` (like map) that will be applied to each record and then call some `action` to call that processing.

You need something like:

```
dataframe.withColumn("latitude", <how to extract latitude>)
         .withColumn("longitude", <how to extract longitude>)
         .select("latitude", "longitude")
         .rdd
         .map(row => <extract values from Row type>)
         .collect()         // this will move data to local collection
```

In case if you can't do it with SQL, you need to do it using RDD:

```
dataframe
     .rdd
     .map(row => <create new row with latitude and longitude>)
     .collect()
```

Comment: no you didn't understand me, i don't want to add columns to the dataframe.
what i want is to save  the langitude and latitude of every row into a variable so i can visualize it within a map later

Comment: i found the action foreach which loop the rdd in spark.
unfortunatly the folium objects aren't serializable, so my problem isn't solved