# Building a dataframe from multiple conditions applied to an initial dataframe : Is this case for pandas rather than pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have what I thought initially would be a trivial problem.

I have a dataset relating to a support ticketing system.
For each ticket, I have the following columns
open_date, last_updated_date, status (only open or closed), product ,customer.

What I want to build is a dataset that summarises the tickets status on a monthly basis.
For each month I want to see the number of tickets open and closed in that month. That is relatively straightforward.
I also want to identify the backlog, by age , at the end of each month. i.e. how many of the tickets open at the end of a month were < 30 days old, 30-60 days old, >60 days old.

So the columns would be :

month, product, customer, Number_opened, Number_Closed, Number<30_days, Number30-60_days,Number>60_days

The basic algorithm would be

```
for each ticket
    increment opened and closed values in corresponding months
    increment relevant backlog age columns in relevant months between opened month and closed month
```

I'm working on a Palantir system based on Spark so i thought that pyspark would be the sword of choice. However, this SO post [how to loop through each row of dataFrame in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349281/how-to-loop-through-each-row-of-dataframe-in-pyspark) seems to say that this is not something to do on Spark, as it is a distributed system that acts more on a columnar basis.

To loop per row, with .collect,  would be equivalent to dumping the dataframe into memory, which in time will cause problems. 
Alternatively, I can export to a pandas dataframe and work that way, but in time, same problems.

Does anyone have another pyspark-esque approach in mind that could do what i'm looking for ?

Best regards,

Colm

P.S. I think that every support team generates this kind of stats so if someone know a magic module out there that already does this then feel free to radically brighten up my day.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at [Koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas), a package that allows for the use of the `pandas` API on Spark data.

E.g.; from their documentation:

```py
import databricks.koalas as ks
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(3), 'y':['a','b','b'], 'z':['a','b','b']})

# Create a Koalas DataFrame from pandas DataFrame
df = ks.from_pandas(pdf)

# Rename the columns
df.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z1']

# Do some operations in place:
df['x2'] = df.x * df.x
```