# Iterating through a particular column values in dataframes using pyspark in azure databricks

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

Hi is it possible to iterate through the values in the dataframe using pyspark code in databricks notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can , You can find lot of options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349281/how-to-loop-through-each-row-of-dataframe-in-pyspark)

```
rows = df3.select('columnname').collect()

final_list = []
for i in rows:
    final_list.append(i[0])

print(final_list)
```