# How to iterate over a pyspark dataframe and create a dictionary out of it

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following `pyspark` dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','a', 'b','b','b','b'],
                    'time': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                    'col': ['1','2','1','2','3','2','3','2']})

foo_df = spark.createDataFrame(foo)
foo_df.show()

+---+----+---+
| id|time|col|
+---+----+---+
|  a|   1|  1|
|  a|   2|  2|
|  a|   3|  1|
|  a|   4|  2|
|  b|   1|  3|
|  b|   2|  2|
|  b|   3|  3|
|  b|   4|  2|
+---+----+---+
```

I would like to iterate over all `id`s and obtain a python dictionary that would have as `keys` the `id` and as `values` the `col` and would look like this:

```
foo_dict = {'a': ['1','2','1','2'], 'b': ['3','2','3','2']})
```

I have in total `10k` `id`s and around `10m` rows in `foo`, so I am looking for an efficient implementation.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pandas dataframe. You should checkout the [documentaton](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/). The dataframe object has inbuilt methods to help iterate, slice and dice your data. There is also this [fun tool](https://pandastutor.com/vis.html) to help you visualize what is going on.

pandas has a ready-made method to convert a dataframe to a dict.

Comment: As mentioned, the question concerns a pyspark dataframe, just initialized as pandas because it is faster. Edited the question, to avoid future confusion

Comment: Just convert df.toPandas() and then use to_dict()

Comment: the pyspark dataframe has 10m rows, so the toPandas() will not work

Comment: The map is the right choice here I think: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349281/how-to-loop-through-each-row-of-dataframe-in-pyspark